# How to make custom Windows commands with support for parameters to run Node.js scripts?

Tags: node.js, cmd

I wish I could create my custom Windows command for example `log` that would execute a .js file for example `app.js` present in my project folder whenever called.

I also want to pass parameters to the command that I could access as variables in my `app.js` file.

In other words:
When I type `log "Hello World"` in Windows command prompt window, `app.js` file is executed and a parameter called `"Hello World"` is passed to it.

My `app.js` file looks like this:

```
// This is app.js file

// This file should be run when I type “log "Hello World" "abcd"” in cmd and we must get those parameters saying "Hello World" and "abcd" to be used as variables in this code

console.log("Hello ", ...cliParameters)
```

Comment: Did you check https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv ?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Creation of a directory for the batch files

In a command prompt window run first the command line:

```
set path
```

There are output the two environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` which are used by the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` to find executables or scripts like batch files entered by the user with just their file names without file extension and without full path. For more details please look at [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

What you need first is to create a directory into which you save the batch files to run he Node.js scripts with the arguments. I suggest to use the following command line for creating such a directory:

```
md "%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles"
```

#### 2. Adding this folder path to USER environment variable PATH

Click on Windows **Start** button and type on keyboard `environment`. Windows offers now in language of Windows:

1. **Edit environment variables for your account**
2. **Edit the system environment variables**

Click on the first item and the dialog window with title **Environment Variables** opens. If there is no environment variable with name `Path` in the upper list, click on button **New** below the upper list, otherwise select `Path` in the upper list and click on button **Edit** below the upper list. Enter `Path` as variable name if that is necessary at all (new variable). Then enter as variable value `%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles` (new variable) or append the folder path `%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles` at end of the variable value respectively at bottom of the folder path list. Finally close both dialog windows with a click on button **OK**.

#### 3. Verify folder path in LOCAL environment variable PATH

Close the already opened command prompt window and open a new one. Run in the newly opened command prompt window:

```
set appdata
set path
```

There should be displayed now the environment variable `PATH` ending with the also displayed folder path of the environment variable `APPDATA` on which `\MyBatFiles` is appended, for example:

```
C:\Users\Ayush Samantaray\AppData\Roaming\MyBatFiles
```

#### 4. Creating a batch file to run a Node.js script with all optional arguments

Let us assume that the *Node.js* script file `app.js` is stored in the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Projects`.

Let us assume next that *Nodejs* is installed into the directory `%LOCALAPPDATA%\nvs\node\17.8.0\x64`.

Then run in the command prompt window:

```
echo @"%%LOCALAPPDATA%%\nvs\node\17.8.0\x64\node.exe" "%%USERPROFILE%%\Projects\app.js" %%*>"%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles\log.cmd"
```

This command line creates in the directory `%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles` a batch file with name `log.cmd` containing the command line:

```
@"%LOCALAPPDATA%\nvs\node\17.8.0\x64\node.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Projects\app.js" %*
```

Run in the command prompt window `call /?` for a description of `%*` at end of this command line which references all argument strings passed to the batch file.

#### 4. How does it work?

Run in the command prompt window:

```
log "Hello World"
```

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` searches now for a file with name `log` with a file extension as in semicolon separated list of environment variable `PATHEXT` in the current directory and next all directories of **local** environment variable `PATH` and finds `log.cmd` in directory `%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles`.

This batch file is processed now by `cmd.exe` with passing the argument string `"Hello World"` to the batch file.

`@` at beginning of the single command line results in suppressing the output of the command line in the command prompt window after replacing all environment variable references like `%LOCALAPPDATA%` or `%USERPROFILE%` by the appropriate values.

So there is executed `node.exe` with its fully qualified file name to process the *Node.js* script file `app.js` specified also with fully qualified file name and with all the arguments passed to the batch file passed further to `node.exe` which passes these argument strings further to the *Node.js* script file.

#### 5. Some more information

I don't have *Node.js* installed and have not read its documentation. So I don't know what is the default installation folder of *Node.js* and where *Node.js* is installed on your computer. I don't know the real file name of the executable of *Node.js* and I don't know which options it supports or requires to run a *Node.js* script file.

There can be used also a different path than `%APPDATA%\MyBatFiles` for your batch files. That is just an example.

If `node.exe` is the real file name of *Node.js* executable and its installation directory is already in either **system** or **user** environment variable `Path`, there can be used also just `node.exe` instead of `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\nvs\node\17.8.0\x64\node.exe"` in the batch files created by you. `cmd.exe` has to search in this case additionally also for `node.exe` after having found `log.cmd` to run this executable.